# Can't use font from ttf file on DrawString

Tags: c#, fonts, .net-core, drawing

I'm trying to create an image by drawing a text using a TTF font. I'm using .net core 2.1.500 on MacOS, and have mono-libgdiplus v5.6 (installed via brew).

The TTF file is [Neo Sans Medium](https://best-font.com/fonts/download-neo-sans-medium-font.html) and this is my code (I tried with different TTF fonts, always with the same result)

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 512))
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.Clear(Color.White);

    var rectf = new RectangleF(0, 40, 1024, 90);

    // If I specify a font that it doesn't know, it defaults to Verdana
    var defaultFont = new Font("DefaultFont", 55);
    Console.WriteLine($"defaultFont: {defaultFont.Name}"); // => defaultFont: Verdana

    g.DrawString("Text with default", defaultFont, Brushes.Black, rectf);

    var privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("/path/to/Neo_Sans_Medium.ttf");
    var fontFamilies = privateFontCollection.Families;

    var family = fontFamilies[0];

    var familyHasRegular = family.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular);
    Console.WriteLine($"familyHasRegular: {familyHasRegular}"); // => familyHasRegular: true

    var textFont = new Font(family, 55);
    Console.WriteLine($"textFont: {textFont.Name}"); // => textFont: Neo Sans

    var rectText = new RectangleF(0, 140, 1024 - 50 - 50, 1024 - 50 - 10);
    g.DrawString("Text with loaded font", textFont, Brushes.Black, rectText);

    g.Flush();

    g.Save();

    bmp.Save("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Since it printed `textFont: Neo Sans`, it seems to me that it was properly loaded (otherwise, it would have defaulted to `Verdana`).

However, the output I'm getting is this one:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it using `SixLabors.ImageSharp`. I also installed `SixLabors.Fonts` and `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing`.

With this code:

```
using (Image<Rgba32> image = new Image<Rgba32>(1024, 512))
{
    FontCollection fonts = new FontCollection();
    fonts.Install("/path/to/Neo_Sans_Medium.ttf");

    var verdana = SystemFonts.CreateFont("Verdana", 55);
    var neoSans = fonts.CreateFont("Neo Sans", 55);

    image.Mutate(x => x
        .BackgroundColor(Rgba32.White)
        .DrawText("Text with default", verdana, Rgba32.Black, new PointF(0, 0))
        .DrawText("Text with loaded font", neoSans, Rgba32.Black, new PointF(0, 65))
    );
    image.Save("out.png");
}
```

I was able to get this:

[image]

Comment: Saved me after three days of attempts. The code in the question works like a charm in any other context (e.g. winforms, wpf, ...) but for a weird reason (that I can't find) it doesn't work in web api (.net core 5)

Answer (score 0):

Hereby example of how to draw with a custom TTF font. No need to install the private font on this system.

The trick is loading the font in a PrivateFontCollection,
then create a new Font using the loaded FontFamily of the collection.

In this example I used a barcode font KixBarcode.

```
    static Bitmap CreateBarcode(string text)
    {
        var collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
        collection.AddFontFile(@"F:\Projects\Tools\Rtf2Pdf\KixBarcode.ttf");
        var image = new Bitmap(300, 300);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        var font = new Font(collection.Families[0], 12);
        g.Dispose();

        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working without switching to a different drawing library. Copy the FFT file to `/usr/share/fonts/` and then switch to using a standard font instead of using PrivateFontCollection.

```
var font = new Font("Your Font Name", 50);
g.DrawString("Hello world", font, Brushes.Black, rectf);
```

Installing the font may seem like a "hack" but if you are deploying your app in a container it's as simple as copying the TTF in your Dockerfile.